# How can I update one table when a referenced table is updated?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Let's say I have two tables: Entries and Entry_Locks.

Entries has 3 columns:

```
Entry_ID (Primary key), 
Entry_Data, 
Entry_Lock_ID (foreign key to Entry_Locks table - references Column Entry_Lock_ID).
```

Entry_Locks has 3 columns:

```
Entry_ID (foreign key to Entries table - references Column Entry_ID),
Entry_Lock_ID (primary key), 
Timestamp.
```

Now I insert a row into Entry_Locks with an `Entry_ID = 50` and `Entry_Lock_ID = 25`.  I would like the row in Entries with `Entry_ID = 50` to automatically have the column Entry_Lock_ID updated with the value 25, to reference the correct Entry_Lock_ID.

Right now my Entry_Locks schema looks like this:

```
entry_lock_id serial NOT NULL,
entry_id text NOT NULL,
"timestamp" date,
CONSTRAINT entry_lock_pkey PRIMARY KEY (entry_lock_id),
CONSTRAINT entry_entry_lock_fkey FOREIGN KEY (entry_id)
  REFERENCES entries (entry_id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I was hoping that adding `ON UPDATE CASCADE` would achieve the desired effect, but the column in Entries is not getting updated as I would like.  How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: It sounds like you have a 1:1 relationship between two tables and want to have foreign keys in each direction.  That doesn't sound like a good idea - pick one foreign key and reference the other ID using it.

Comment: @D Stanley So you would recommend removing the entry_lock_id from the entries table, and the corresponding foreign key?  Then the reference would exist only on the entry_locks table, via the entry_id field?

Comment: That would be one option; another option is to just merge the two tables into one by moving the `Timestamp` field to `Entries` (since the primary key and foreign key would not longer be necessary).

Comment: Interesting.  I am going to see what I can do.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Yeah this design is weird you have a primary key on both tables acting as a foreign key on both tables? Would review this design a bit.

Comment: Is the Entry_Lock_ID column of Entry ever updated directly (by updating Entry)?

Comment: I ended up removing the entry_lock_id column.  The design was a little weird.  Now entry_id is the primary key for both tables and it works as I would like.  Don't know why I tried to do it the other way now that I look at it.